# Why won't Lamar inject type of IServiceScopeFactory in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: lamar

I am trying to implement a health check in an aspnetcore2.2 project which asserts that my Lamar container configuration is valid via `IContainer.AssertConfigurationIsValid` (essentially that it can construct all dependencies).

A couple of services (outside my control) are depending on an instance of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceScopeFactory`. Lamar cannot inject any of these dependencies, which then fails the assertion when these services cannot be constructed.

The stack is an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application using Lamar as default IoC framework (via the recommended `.UseLamar()` extension method) and everything else is working fine.

Any take on injecting `ServiceScopeFactory` (anywhere) fails with

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Frame type Lamar.IoC.Resolvers.CastRootScopeFrame does not implement IResolverFrame
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.FuncResolverDefinition.BuildResolver()
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.GeneratedInstance.BuildFuncResolver(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.GeneratedInstance.buildResolver(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.GeneratedInstance.ToResolver(Scope topScope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.ConstructorInstance.ToResolver(Scope topScope)
   at Lamar.ServiceGraph.FindResolver(Type serviceType)
   at Lamar.IoC.Scope.TryGetInstance(Type serviceType)
   at Lamar.IoC.Scope.GetService(Type serviceType)
(...)
```

How come this particular dependency cannot be injected with Lamar?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem, I found that `IServiceScopeFactory`, in my case, is used when managing HangFireSession. So changing `IServiceScopeFactory` to `IServiceProvider` and creating a scope from it fixed my issue.

**Solution 1:** `IServiceScopeFactory` and `IServiceProvider` are quite the same.

This is the behavior of CreateScope from `IServiceProvider`, it just wrap `IServiceScopeFactory`.

```cs
public static IServiceScope CreateScope(this IServiceProvider provider)
{
    return provider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope();
}
```

PR is submitted reproducing the bug https://github.com/JasperFx/lamar/pull/228

**Solution 2:** Inject a `Func<IServiceScopeFactory>` instead of `IServiceScopeFactory`